Doing it something in certain time
I want to say that I will be able to do something in certain time by some point in the futre. For instane since Monday I will have the ability to complete something in 2 days.

By Monday I will be doing it in 2 days

By Monday I will have been doing it in 2 days


I know sentennce 1 is quite akward. 2 is even more akward but still correct, right?
One more question, would 2 still be fine if we changed "By Monday" to for instance "next week" or "on Monday"?


I downvoted for the several spelling mistakes. 2. If you want to say you are going to do something in the future then say: *In two days' time I will be doing it*


So many spelling mistakes in such a short post. Mistakes that would not occur if you turned on your spellchecker Turn Chrome spell check on and off

Gregor, my advice to you is not to use meaningless prepositions like "it".  Use real-world examples in your questions, buying a car, getting married,  taking a test, selling a house, traveling to a city, etc.. "doing it" is just too vague.

Both of your sentences are not just awkward (please use a spellchecker!) but nonsense.
If you will do something in two days, you will do it two days from now. Today is Friday, so you will do it on Sunday.
If you are going to start on Saturday, by Monday you will have been doing it for two days.

I thought that 1 and 2 mean that when Monday comes then I'm able to do or perform some action in 2 days. That's wrong?

what do you think?

You would say "It will take me two days, starting on Monday" or "I'll start on Monday and it will take two days".
